# A comparison between the verbs "To put in order" and "tidy (up)"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

Dictionaries acknowledge that **to put (something) in order** means: "to clean or tidy something". Also, **tidy (up) something** means: "to make a place or a collection of things tidy."

Now, I need to know how the following sentences differ in meaning:

> 1-1- Help me **put the house in order** before mom and dad get back. 
>   1-2- Help me **tidy up the house** before mom and dad get back.

And

> 2-1- **Put** all these books **in order.** 
>   2-2- **Tidy up** all these books.

And finally:

> 3-1-I'm tired of asking you to **tidy your room up.** 
>   3-2- I'm tired of asking you to **put your room in order.**

To me both sentences in each group are interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the example usages are similar, there is a difference. The phrase "to put in order" can be more extreme than "to tidy up". For example after a party I might say

> Help me tidy up the house before mom and dad get back.

But if the party went wild, with the sofa in the pool and the curtains pulled down, I might say

> Help me put the house in order before mom and dad get back.

There is a figurative use of "to put the house in order" too. Suppose someone has taken to gambling, is in debt and has lost his job. I might say

> You must put your house in order.

and this has nothing to do with tidying up a home, but making drastic changes to one's lifestyle.

There is also a difference in meaning with the question's second pair of sentences:

> Put all these books in order.

They may have been tidy, but not in **alphabetical order**, which is what I would expect the instruction to mean: to **sort** into order.

Comment: Thank you @Weather Vane, but how about the other two? :)

Comment: They are similar, but "put the house in order" could be a more extreme tidying up, for example after a wild party when the sofa is in the garden and all the crockery is in the pool.

Comment: But @Weather Vane I guess as in #1&3, depending on the context, also in #2 both sentences (verbs) can convey the same message too. Am I right, or irrespective of the context, the two verbs convey different messages in #2? I wonder if you could explain it too. :)

Comment: @A-friend I have improved this answer.